# Bigger Touch when touching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need a way for the user to have a bigger touch when in comes to pressing a button. This way the user can miss the button but still click it. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to change the button class just the area in which the user clicks..

Thanks!!!
p.s I'm pretty good at logical thinking... I just need some code

Comment: Why can't you make the button bigger?  You can make the button have no border and there are properties to off set the content in the button.   Otherwise you will have to have the parent uiview as the touch listener and then that would have to figure out which button was the closest to the touch.

Comment: I'm not really using a "button."I have a custom slider that i can't slide because the image is too small. I do not want to increase the image, I just want a margin of error around the slider so a user can access it easier.:)

Comment: I would put the slider only  in a UIView then have the uiview and the slider both take events and if the touch is just outside the slider then the parent view would get the touch even and have it determin where it is and send new pos to the slider.

Comment: Is this custom slider a subclass of `UISlider`, or `UIView`, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

1)you can use [yourButtonType setBackgroundImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
you could make you image like this,

```
-------------------------------------------
| transparent, transparent, transparent   |
| transparent,yourOpaqueImage, transparent|
| transparent, transparent, transparent   |
|------------------------------------------
```

In fact the button frame is larger , but the user can not aware

2)you can use touchesEnded,like this

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGRect btnRect = CGRectMake(btn.frame.origon.x-10,btn.frame.origon.y-10 , btn.frame.size.width+20, btn.frame.size.height+20);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(btnRect, location)) {
         //sender your button
    }
}
```